# Using Flyway in modular applications

Tags: flyway

We have a modular application, each app creates its own tables (typically one two) and manage the data.

We use Flyway in our main application but also need it for our modules. However, if we add the patches to our main application, ALTER TABLE queries won't work for some deployments if the corresponding module is not installed.

One way to solve this issue is to perform the schema evolution with multiple Flyway operations, each module gets its own Flyway and manage itself. However since Flyway creates tables for managing the state we ended up too much tables since we have ~20 modules right now.

What's the elegant way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would say having the migrations managed by the unit of software it is supporting is the cleanest and trumps "too many tables". In terms of neat organisation of those tables, you can silo those using a schema (if you RDBMS supports those) and Flyway lets you name the table that is used per migration managed application.

The key thing here is "modules". From your description, it sounds like not all applications are made up of the same modules. I would ask you, if we go to the effort of making our modules descrete to create decoupled / reusable software - why should database schemas of those modules be treated any different?

To counter your concern about "too many tables", lets try and debunk the costs of that.

1. Volume. Your RDBMS is made to handle thousands, there is no cost there.
2. Operational. Flyway does all the management here, they are effectively opaque to you.
3. Performance. They are a deployment concern, not a runtime liability.
4. Organisational. Hide them / name them with the methods mentioned above.

Our natural urge is to aggregate related things but doesn't always lead to the best outcome, so we must be pragmatic. In this situation, good/flexible design trumps aggregation.